# Django Error en campo con valor único IntegrityError at

Tags: python, django

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto en el que necesito crear un valor único en uno de los modelos con un campo nombre, el valor se genera a partir de 2 datos, tipo_aula + numero. El aula puede ser un salón, un auditorio, un laboratorio, una sala de sistemas, etc.

Modelo tipo de aula

```
class TipoAula(MarcadorTiempo):
nombre = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='nombre')

class Meta:
    verbose_name = 'tipo de aula'
    verbose_name_plural = 'tipos de aula'
    ordering = ['nombre']

def __str__(self):
    return '%s' % self.nombre
```

Modelo recurso (padre)

```
class Recurso(models.Model):
numero = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='numero', null=True, blank=True)
contenido = models.TextField(verbose_name='contenido', null=True, blank=True)
caracteristicas = models.TextField(verbose_name='caracteristicas', null=True, blank=True)

class Meta:
    verbose_name = 'recurso'
    verbose_name_plural = 'recursos'
```

Modelo recurso físico (hijo)

```
class RecursoFisico(MarcadorTiempo, Recurso):
tipo_aula = models.ForeignKey(TipoAula, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='tipo de aula',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
nombre = models.CharField(max_length=40, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='nombre', unique=True)
capacidad = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='capacidad', null=True, blank=True)
ubicacion = models.CharField(max_length=40, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='ubicación')

class Meta:
    verbose_name = 'recurso fisico'
    verbose_name_plural = 'recursos fisicos'
    ordering = ['nombre']

def __str__(self):
    return '%s' % self.nombre

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    [![if][1]][1] not self.nombre:
        self.nombre = '%s %s' % (self.tipo_aula, self.numero)

    return super(RecursoFisico, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Admin

```
class RecursoFisicoAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
fields = ['tipo_aula', 'numero', 'nombre', 'ubicacion', 'capacidad', 'caracteristicas', 'contenido', 'fecha_creacion', 'fecha_modificacion']
readonly_fields = ['nombre', 'fecha_creacion', 'fecha_modificacion']

admin.site.register(RecursoFisico, RecursoFisicoAdmin)
```

Intencional mente cree un aula con un nombre ya existente porque seguramente un usuario podría hacerlo sin no se fija.

[image: Intencional mente cree un aula con un nombre ya existente porque seguramente un usuario podría hacerlo sin no se fija.]

Esta acción me genera el siguiente error.

[image: Esta acción me genera el siguiente error.]

Como puedo controlar esta excepción para que me muestre un mensaje informado que ya existe el nombre que se esta tratando de crear

Un mensaje como el que se ve en esta confirmación de creación

[image: Un mensaje como el que se ve en esta confirmación de creación]

En este enlace se encuentra el código del proyecto: [github](https://github.com/ceragos/sisgerecu)

Answer (score 0):

Reemplaze su modelo por este:

```
class RecursoFisico(MarcadorTiempo, Recurso):
      tipo_aula = models.ForeignKey(TipoAula, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='tipo de aula',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
      nombre = models.CharField(max_length=40, null=False, blank=True, verbose_name='nombre', unique=True)
      capacidad = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='capacidad', null=True, blank=True)
      ubicacion = models.CharField(max_length=40, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='ubicación')
```

Comment: Disculpa, no veo cual seria la diferencia con el modelo que tengo actualmente

Comment: En el campo tú tienes null=True, pon null=False